# Cocos2D autoration shifted by 90 Degrees

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, rotation

When autorotating, I set

```
GAME_AUTOROTATION = kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

and

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController    
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

This means that if I hold the device in either landscape orientation it will autorotate. The thing is, the rotation is always shifted by 90 degrees (ie when I rotate to landscape right I get portrait).

How do I go along in fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to set `GAME_AUTOROTATION` is this:

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

(I have mine in GameConfig.h.)

I can't make sense of `GAME_AUTOROTATION = kGameAutorotationUIViewController`, so just thinking this could be the cause of the problem (if you used it like that).

In any case, if you still have problems with autorotation, set a breakpoint in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and inspect what happens from there; same with `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the code and turns out I changed this line earlier (LANDSCAPELEFT INSTEAD OF PORTRAIT).

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
 [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];